# Selenium find_element broke for loop

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web

I find elements with *find_elements* and after getting child elements with *find_element*, but the iteration doesn't work further after *find_element* and the loop stops (although there are several elements found with *find_elements*)

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

def getItems(url, xpath):
   path_to_browser = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "\\driver\\chromedriver"
   service = Service(executable_path=path_to_browser)
   browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
   browser.get(url)
        
   # wait until page is succesfully loaded
   WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

   return browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)

items = getItems("https://lamoda.ru/c/4153/default-women/?is_sale=1", "/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div")
for idx, item in enumerate(items):
    # only print element with index 0, and stops
    print(idx)
    print(item.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[2]").text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because this locator return only a single element, so the for loop runs only once, Also i would suggest using stable locators instead of indexed xpaths

Try below

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


def getItems(url, xpath):
    path_to_browser = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "\\driver\\chromedriver"
    service = Service(executable_path=path_to_browser)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    browser.get(url)

    # wait until page is succesfully loaded
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

    return browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)


items = getItems("https://lamoda.ru/c/4153/default-women/?is_sale=1",
                 '//div[contains(@class,"x-product-card__link")]')
for idx, item in enumerate(items):
    # only print element with index 0, and stops
    print(idx)
    print(item.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(@class,'x-product-card-description__price-new')]").text)
```

Should print All 60

```
0
849 ₽
1
3 890 ₽
2
10 990 ₽
3
660 ₽
4
3 890 ₽
5
3 595 ₽
6
8 240 ₽
7
790 ₽
8
57 810 ₽
9
5 199 ₽
10
5 090 ₽
11
1 799 ₽
..
```